# Is the expression "without gym" correct? If yes in which context?

Tags: grammaticality

The expression "without a gym" (e.g. working out without a gym) is as far as I know correct. Is "without gym" also correct? If yes, what is the difference in meaning and what is the proper context of use?

Comment: My buddy is really good at analyzing syntactic conundrums like this. I'm sorry, but I can't answer this without Jim.

Comment: @DanBron - I got ya covered...

Comment: @DanBron I'm sure you could work out something on your own.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth If your comment was a joke, I don't get it. If it wasn't a joke, you didn't get mine (which I think may be the case given the earlier formulation "exercise restraint"?).

Comment: @DanBron Jym ... buddy ... absent ... work out on your own. The 'exercise restraint' was a weak riposte to your 'Your puns are getting dicey'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Oh, I didn't connect "Jim" and "buddy", that's actually really clever. Well done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When saying "without gym" you would be referring to gym as an abstract noun or an idea, such as math or science, which would also be used as "without math." This would most commonly refer to gym as a class, like P.E. "Without a gym" uses gym as a concrete noun, a physical place, basically, such as a library (without a library).

Comment: Perhaps it is simply the sense of *without* meaning *outside of*. The next village to mine has the word *Without* as part of its name - such as *Kidminster Without*. It just means that the parish of *Kidminster Without* is just outside of Kidminster.